# How to convert one object to another when both are different types but inherit from the same parent class

Tags: c#

I have 2 objects, Object A and Object B. A has the properties color and size and B has the the properties color, size and depth.

Both A and B inherits from C which is an abstract class.

How can I convert B to A at run-time?

```
 abstract class C {

 }

 Class A: C {
     int color;
     int size;
 }

 Class B: C {
     int color;
     int size;
     int depth;
 }

 main() {
     //creating object A
     A objA = new A();
     A.color = 46;
     A.size = 90;

     //creating object B
     B objB = new B();
     B.color = 23;
     B.size = 10;
     B.depth = 78;

     //How to do casting 
     A = B;
 }
```

Comment: You can't cast A to B in this case. Why not just move the common fields into the base class?

Comment: So what happens to `B.depth` when it gets copied to `A`?

Comment: I want the program to ignore  depth when casting from B to A.

Comment: Cat and Dog both inherit from Animal. Why can't I cast a dog to a cat?

Comment: Actually I am working on shapes ie ellipse and circle and I want to cast ellipse to circle for some mathematical calculations. I put A, B C for simplicicity

Comment: You should rethink your class structure, all circles are ellipses with equal major and minor axis. Just to give a complex example, here is how I would define a square: `Shape->Polygon->Quadrilateral->Parallelogram->Rectangle->Square` As all squares are rectangles (and all rectangles are parallelograms and so on). Each layer can hold a piece of common information, for example `Shape` would hold the color, `Polygon` would hold the number of sides, ect... Some things like square would just be a wrapper for a parent class `class Square : Rectangle { public square(int x) : base(x,x) {} }`

Answer (score 10):

You can add an explicit cast operator to the in class `B`:

```
Class B: C {
    int color;
    int size;
    int depth;
    public static explicit operator A(B b)
    {
        return new A() {color = b.color, size = b.size};
    }
}
```

You can then convert a `B` to an `A` using a cast:

```
A a = (A)b;
```

Answer (score 7):

When I've had problems like this I've used AutoMapper.

This is a free library that will allow you to map one object to another and even allow you to map one field to another of a different name and type.

You can also convert a `List<A>` to `List<B>` which is handy.

[AutoMapper Link on github](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper)

**Edit**

After reading your last comment I think AutoMapper might be your solution.

You do not explicitly need to specify anything other than;

```
AutoMapper.CreateMap<A,B>();
```

Then you can map;

```
B b = Mapper.Map<A,B>(sourceA);
```

**Edit 2**

Or use reflection yourself and create an extension that takes A as an argument and copies the appropriate fields / properties from A to B.

Comment: Valid answer.. however I think an even more appropriate answer is "rethink your design" :)

Comment: Sometimes you are handed objects that are outside of your design influence which I suspect is why AutoMapper was created.  :)

Comment: That or you are doing something like using Data Transfer Objects that do not necessarily inherit from the original source datatype.

Comment: Or even getting an object from a web service that doesn't conform to any of your database objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly convert B to A in this case without some extra work.

if you move the common fields into the base class then you can pass a B into a method that expects an instance of the base class and it will just access the common fields.

Your other options if you don't want to do that are to write a conversion method or add an [implicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) conversion so you can cast B to A or to use a library like Automapper as had been suggested

implicit conversion could look something like this

```
Public static implicit operator A (B theB)
{
    return new A (theB.colour, theB.size);
}
```

And would then allow you to cast your B instance to an A instance.

```
A myA = (A)myB;
```

I would still question if this is a good idea

Comment: With the implicit operator you don't need to specify the cast. You can just write "A myA = myB;".

Answer (score 0):

It won't work like this.
You are making two different variables with almost same attributes inside ?!
Why so?

You can cast common fields into base class ! It is the best way here.